# How to define DateTime property for a db table model object when there is a NULL value in database

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

I am defining a database model property like this.

```
class GuestList extends DatabaseModel
{
    protected static $table = 'GuestLists';

    public $ID;
    public $EventName;
    public \DateTime $EventDateTime;
   
}
```

But its throwing a fatal error. because there are already some data in that table and for some row the value in the EventDateTime is NULL. If i dont  set `\DateTime`  the error goes away. But is there any way so the fiels also accepts Null value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add [nullable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.nullable) type hint by prefixing `?` to your other type hint:

```php
class GuestList extends DatabaseModel
{
    protected static $table = 'GuestLists';

    public $ID;
    public $EventName;
    public ?\DateTime $EventDateTime;
}
```